# Can I run Orange widgets from normal Python scripts?

Tags: python, orange

I'd like to do normal machine learning with Python and Sklearn, but occasionally use the nice graphical widgets or Orange for presentation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Orange was ever intended to be used that way, but if you can convert your data into `Orange.data.Table`, you might be able to instantiate the widgets you need with it.

See the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block at the bottom of most widgets for some example.